# Problem to start Odoo in CLI with configuration file

Tags: command-line-interface, odoo, configuration-files

I'm on a VM with Ubuntu 17.10 and Odoo 11.
I tried to launch Odoo in Command Line interface.

I stopped the service with `sudo systemctl stop odoo` and re-executed it with the command `python3 /usr/bin/odoo -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf`.

The command works without blocking errors, but when I try to access to Odoo in my browser, there is no connexion on the terminal, and no acces in the browser:

I tried too to only execute `python3 /usr/bin/odoo` and it works, I have a connexion (but it tells me there is no database and I have to create one, otherwise I really have databases)

So my question is : **is there a problem with my configuration file** ? because without it odoo aproximatively works, and with it my navigator can't access to Odoo

Please tell me if you want to see some variables in the configuration file

EDIT  :

[image: Configuration file]

EDIT 2:

1) The command you write do really nothing :
[image]
Instead of my command :
[image]

2) For the listen ports (i re-activated odoo with systemd) I've g ot this : I think odoo is :8069 and postgres :5432
[image]

3) odoo user connexion's to postgres is working :
[image]

EDIT 3:
Without misspelling:
[image]

Now WITHOUT re-typing systemd
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's systemd user has privileges on the database while your user `adquat` does not.

```
sudo su -l postgres -c "psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <database_name> TO adquat;'"
```

Comment: I tried this, I have the error `sudo postgres : command not found`

Comment: Oops! It's `sudo -l postgres ...` I have already edited the answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Oops! My mistake again. This one should work. `sudo` invokes superpowers to be able to impersonate another user `su -l postgres` and run a SQL command

Comment: Can you connect manually to the database (logged in as `adquat`)? `psql <database_name>`. Right now, you should. If so, please post the variables related to the database connection from your Odoo config.

Comment: Yes I do `sudo su adquat ` then `psql emballego`

Comment: From your config file, I see that the account to connect to the database is `odoo`. So, can you connect to the database as `odoo`? If you can't, try granting  privileges  to `odoo`

Comment: When I do `psql emballego odoo` I have the error FATAL peer autentification failed for odoo user. Same after grant privileges to odoo

Comment: EDIT :
Ok I see my error I didn't edit the /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf file.
But it does not solve my initial problem

Comment: What happens if you run it as `odoo`? `sudo su -l odoo -c "python3 /usr/bin/odoo -c /etc/odoo/odoo"`

Comment: Nothing happens :(

Comment: Sorry, your answer doesn't help me to help you. What can you tell? Does Odoo run? Is it bound to the port 8069? Can you browse to `localhost:8069`? What does `localhost:8069/web/database/manager` show?

Comment: Are your existing databases Odoo-generated? If the answer is no, that's your problem. Odoo will only show the databases it recognizes.

Comment: Sorry, when I execute your command Odoo does not run, my terminal is at the same point than before your command. The databases are Odoo-generated

Comment: Hm!... we both made a mistake. I copied the command from your question text then I realized that the config file name was wrong from the first screenshot. May I give you some piece of advice? Learn a little bit of Bash. At least do `man <command>` before executing a command you don't understand. So, anyway, let's try again: `sudo su -l odoo -c "python3 /usr/bin/odoo -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf"` That should make odoo start the same way it is started by systemd.

Comment: Also, see if both Odoo and PostgreSQL are working by reviewing the results of `netstat -tupan | grep LISTEN`: Under program name, look for python3 listening on port 8069 and for postgres listening on port 5432. Please, post those two rows.

Comment: Finally, double check that user `odoo` can connect to the desired database: `psql emballego odoo`. If everything is Ok you should have a fully-working Odoo and your problem is the (virtual) network configuration of your VM.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake on spelling... for your 3 last comments i edited the question to show you screenshots, please look at the EDIT 2

Comment: You misspelled the command I wrote: There is a `l-` instead of a `-c`. READ the man pages!!: `man su`, `man sudo`.

Comment: So, referring to EDIT 2, that's how the ports and database connection should look. If you can't access Odoo, the problem is neither Odoo nor its configuration, it's your network meaning firewall and/or network configuration. Your question is answered: There's no problem with your odoo configuration.

Comment: Man su and man sudo tell me that I use command as superuser I know it, so what ?
Sorry for the misspelling again, I've re-posted my result (or no-result) ; and for the ports i said it's when I re-activated odoo systemd (to test), but if I leave it I don't have 8069 (see EDIT 3)

Comment: It seems like the user `odoo` has been forbidden from running shell commands. To confirm this check the `passwd` config file: `grep odoo /etc/passwd` and make sure the last field is a valid shell (kinda `/bin/bash`). If it ends with `/bin/false` that's the reason you can't run it.